# Struts 2 Validation w/ annotations getting a null exception

Tags: validation, exception, struts2

We're trying to use Struts 2 Validation w/ Annotations and we've ran into a weird problem.  We have a method that we have specified a string validation for.  When we run that method we get a NullException in the AnnotationValidationConfigurationBuilder on line 580.  We took a look and it appears that the validationFactory is null.  We traced that back and can't find a reason why it would be null though we did notice an @Inject annotation on the setValidatorFactory.

As a side note we're also using Spring 2 in the mix and calling it from the jQuery plugin.

Has anyone run into this before?  We've looked at all the docs and none of them talk about needing to register a bean with Spring or anything like that.

Thanks,

Shane

Comment: Please show the code of the action.  Minimal code that demonstrates the issue along with the parts of the spring xml file which are injected into the action would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the answer.  Apparently if you have a validators.xml you need to specify everything in the base validators.xml.  This has changed since we used this in the past without needing to do this.