# Struts 2 stack trace after upgrading from 2.2.1.1 to 2.3.8

Tags: struts2

This is a mystery to me, can anyone shed some light on to the possible cause here ?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationValidationConfigurationBuilder.processVisitorFieldValidatorAnnotation(AnnotationValidationConfigurationBuilder.java:485)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationValidationConfigurationBuilder.processAnnotations(AnnotationValidationConfigurationBuilder.java:208)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationValidationConfigurationBuilder.buildAnnotationClassValidatorConfigs(AnnotationValidationConfigurationBuilder.java:781)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildClassValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:283)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:371)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.getValidators(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:102)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:128)
```

Comment: I guess no, unless you post your code :/

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe yess :)

I found out this answer

[Struts 2 Validation w/ annotations getting a null exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652195/struts-2-validation-w-annotations-getting-a-null-exception)

it doens't mention the versions but according to the release dates and the date of the answer, it could be the same problem.

Check out the solution provided (specifies everything in the base Validators.xml) and see if it works

Comment: What is "base" in this context? I have one validators.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the DOCTYPE for validators.xml had changed. Updating URL-reference fixed it.